# Order of measurement of two observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, commutator, wavefunction-collapse

Let $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ be two operators representing the observables $A$ and $B$, and let $\Psi(t)$ be the state of a quantum system. Let's suppose that we measure $A$ at $t_0$ and just after that we measure $B$, getting the results $a$ and $b$.

If we had made the measurements in the opposite order ($A$ first and $B$ after it), under what conditions would we have obtained the same values $a$ and $b$ for $A$ and $B$?

---

**My attempt at a solution**

I see that, after measuring $A$ or $B$, the system will collapse to one of the eigenstates of these operators. For instance, if we measure $A$ in first place, then the state at $t_0$ sill be $\Psi(x,t_0)=\psi_a(x)$, with $\psi_a(x)$ the eigenstate of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $a$. And I also see that, if $\psi_a(x)$ is also an eigenfunction of $B$, and we call it's eigenvalue $b$, then the order won't matter. So this would be true if $[\hat A, \hat B]=0$ and $A$ and $B$ non-degenerate.

However, I'm not sure about the case one (of both) of the operators is degenerate, or about the case they don't commute...

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I see that, after measuring $A$ or $B$, the system will collapse to one of the eigenstates of these operators. For instance, if we measure $A$ in first place, then the state at $t_0$ sill be $\Psi(x,t_0)=\psi_a(x)$, with $\psi_a(x)$ the eigenstate of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $a$. And I also see that, if $\psi_a(x)$ is also an eigenfunction of $B$, and we call it's eigenvalue $b$, then the order won't matter. However, this is just a special case, I'm not sure about what happens in general...

Comment: By "obtaining the same values", do you mean having the same probability of getting those same values? Certainly even if you performed the $A$ then $B$ measurement again you would not be guaranteed to get the same results. There is no guarantee of measurements at all. So are you meaning to ask about obtaining the same probability distributions? i.e. $P(a\text{ and }b|A\text{ then }B)=P(a\text{ and }b|B\text{ then }A)$?

Comment: 1) You should definitely add your thinking to the question. 2) The question isn't aren't asking for  a "general" answer, it's asking what conditions need to be met for something to happen.

Comment: @BioPhysicist As I see it, the question is asking for conditions that the state $\Psi(t)$ has to satisfy in *order* for this to be guaranteed.

Comment: I have just added my attempt to the question.

Comment: I think that is not about the state $\Psi(t)$, but about the operators. The question is about the hypothetical case that we could make the measurement of $B$ first and $A$ after under exactly the same conditions we had when we made the measurements in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right parsing of the question here is “under what conditions on the operators would we have obtained the same joint probability distribution for $(a, b)$ for arbitrary $\Psi$?”

## Background

This is really easy to state in terms of projectors but there is a decent chance that you have not seen those yet so let me introduce them here.

These observables define [PVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure) $M_a$ and $N_b$ such that $$\operatorname{Prob}(A = a) = \langle \Psi | M_a |\Psi\rangle,\\
\operatorname{Prob}(B = b) = \langle \Psi | N_b |\Psi\rangle,\\
M_a M_{a'} = \delta_{aa'} M_a,\\
N_b N_{b'} = \delta_{bb'} N_b.$$
If you have never seen this before, imagine that we index all of the eigenvectors $|m_i(a)\rangle$ compatible with observing $a$ with index $i$, then $M_a = \sum_i |m_i(a)\rangle \langle m_i(a)|$ is the projector onto the states compatible with $A=a$, so these are also self-adjoint if that wasn't totally obvious from the above.

After observing $A=a$ the state collapses to the state $M_a |\Psi\rangle$ and then the probability of observing $B = b$ by the above rules must be $$\operatorname{Prob}_{A\text{-then-}B}(a,b) = \langle \Psi|M_a N_b M_a |\Psi\rangle,\\
\operatorname{Prob}_{B\text{-then-}A}(a,b) = \langle \Psi|N_b M_a N_b |\Psi\rangle,
$$ and asserting that these are the same for arbitrary $|\Psi\rangle$ ultimately forces $M_a N_b M_a - N_b M_a N_b = \hat 0$ as the zero operator is the only operator which has average zero for arbitrary $|\Psi\rangle$.

## Your question

So if we boil down the math to these PVMs, the question is “under what conditions of the operators would we have that their projectors satisfy $M_a N_b M_a = N_b M_a N_b$, for all $(a, b)$ we could measure?”

We have not used one important point, which is that these operators are projectors. Let us drop the subscripts and just assume we fix $a, b$ and $M = M_a$ is our shorthand. Then it is straightforward to say that $$ M N M = N M M + [M, N] M = N M + [M, N] M,\\
N M N = N N M + N [M, N] = N M + N [M, N]$$ so on projectors, the criterion $MNM = NMN$ is equivalent to saying that $[M, N] M = N [M, N].$

Clearly $[M, N] = 0$ (that is to say: for all $a, b: [M_a, N_b] = 0$) is sufficient to guarantee this last equation (it will say $0 = 0$ then which is obviously true). We can then reconstruct $A = \sum_a a M_a$ and $B = \sum_b b M_b$ to find that $[A, B] = 0$, and this argument reverses perfectly: $[A, B] = 0$ is sufficient to guarantee that the joint probability distribution is the same for arbitrary $\Psi.$

The only question which remains is that of proving that from this $[M, N] = 0$ is *necessary* rather than sufficient. That looks somewhat nontrivial and probably requires diving deep into the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $M, N$ and repeatedly using the fact that the eigenvalues must be either $0$ or $1$ by construction.

Comment: (Nice answer!) Start with $\vert\Psi\rangle$ an eigenstate of $\sigma_z$; measure $\sigma_x$ then $\sigma_y$, and then do this in the reverse order.  If I did it correctly the probs are then same.  This is so because your PVM are actually sensitive to average values and it’s quite possible for operators to be different but have the same average values on some states.  Of course for this I had to choose a specific state $\vert \Psi\rangle$.